# dns cifs share entry in fstab not re-mounted on IP change, while used by smbd

Tags: mount, cifs, fstab

I set up a CIFS share on my ubuntu

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
```

using an fstab entry:

```
//mystr.myserver.com/backup /mnt/mystr       cifs    iocharset=utf8,rw,_netdev,credentials=/etc/smb/mystr-credentials,uid=someuser,gid=0,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 0       0
```

which works as expected.

now i do have `smbd` running to provide this share to users on my LAN with this section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[mystr]
path = /mnt/mystr
public = yes
writeable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
force user = someuser
```

which also works fine.

However there seems to be an issue if the IP address of the entry `mystr.myserver.com` changes. The share says `"Host is down."` and `mount` shows me the outdated IP address.

As this does not happen very often it is not easy to reproduce.
This morning I wanted to fix it manually and tried to unmount it first which gave me `Resource is busy` as I think the `smbd` process is blocking the share.

Stopping the `smbd` process, unmounting the share, using `mount -a` and restarting `smbd` solved the issue.

So my questions are:
Can this be done automatically?
Can I tell `fstab` to force re-mounting the share if it is down?
Is this even related to `smbd` having a handle on the directory?
I checked `lsof`, but could not find anything related.
Can I tell samba to "let go" of unreachable directories?

Thanks in advance  for any ideas/Suggestions.

Comment: configure your server with a fixed IP.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider although ´mystr.myserver.com´ might indicate it is my server  - i can not control the ip address of this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly i could not find a way to do this automatically so i wrote a script and added it to `crontab`

this is now running once every minute.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in $(find /mnt/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do
        if [[ "$d" == *"Host is down"* ]]; then
                $(systemctl stop smbd)
                $(umount -a -t cifs -l)
                $(mount -a)
                $(systemctl start smbd)
        fi
done
```

I'm using `unmount` for each `CIFS` storage and `remount` them using `mount -a` once the script detects a offline mount with the message `Host is down`. Maybe stopping `smbd` is not necessary but shouldn't cause any issues here.

this might not be ideal, but does the job.